# Append pyodbc.Rows into a data frame using a loop

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pyodbc

I am trying to import some data from a sql server to python. I would like to import the data row by row and append it to a data frame iteratively.

My code so far is:

```
data_NS = pd.DataFrame(columns=Fields_NS)
i=0

while(i < 10):
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    rowAsList = list(row)
    data_NS.append(rowAsList)
    i = i+1
conn.close()
```

The result for data_NS is and empty data frame.
I am not receiving any error messages so any information will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you post Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think you probably want to use `fetchall()` and iterate through that response.

Comment: `rowAsList = [x for x in row]` is a bit redundant. Maybe `list(row)`? Also, you should use a `for` loop for a definite number of iterations, not a `while` loop with an external counter.

Comment: The sql file is too large to use fetchall(), it returns a memory issue error. As for the while loop, I intend to let this iterate through the entire file once the above problem is tackled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DataFrame is remaining empty because [DataFrame.append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) will

> Append rows of other to the end of this frame, **returning a new object**.

(Emphasis mine.) So simply doing

```python
data_NS.append(...)
```

will take the existing `data_NS` frame, append stuff to it, and return the result as a new frame, which is then discarded because it is not assigned to a variable.

I think you're actually trying to do something more like this:

```python
fields_NS = ["id", "txt"]
data_NS = pd.DataFrame(columns=fields_NS)

sql = """\
SELECT 1 AS id, 'foo' as txt
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS id, 'bar' as txt
"""
crsr.execute(sql)

i = 0
while i < 10:
    row = crsr.fetchone()
    if not row:
        break
    row_as_dict = dict(zip(fields_NS, row))
    data_NS = data_NS.append(row_as_dict, ignore_index=True)
    i += 1
```

but beware that such row-by-row appends might be rather slow.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Would yo be able to explain why you needed to convert the row object to a dict?

Comment: `append` didn't seem to like a simple ordered list of values. It appeared to want a dict of name/value pairs so it could plug the correct value into the appropriate column in the frame.

Answer (score 2):

I would try it like this:

```
connection = pyodbc.connect('your server information')
query = 'SELECT TOP 100 * FROM table'
df = pd.read_sql_query(query, connection)
```

To avoid a memory error, just adjust your query and only select the columns you need, or adjust the number of rows you bring back using "TOP" or something similar depending on the type of database you are querying.

Comment: This method seems to be about 100 times faster than appending each row separately